# Get Project Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with few projects.

Solution 1 has

Pro1 (MVC project),
Pro2 (Class Library), and
Pro3 (Class Library)

So I use Pro 3 for the reporting part and using hkHtmlToPDF for exporting htmls as pdf. There is a exe called hkHtmlToPdf.exe for doing my task. 
But I have very little issue. It is needed exe path to execute the code. I want to get Pro3 physical path and used below code to get the path.

```
var myPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Above code returns web project path. Actually I need Pro3 path. How to get it?

Comment: Why is that for minus mark for the question? I searching this for 1, 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You know the name of your exe file.

```
string pattern = "hkHtmlToPdf.exe";
string dirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
Directory.GetFiles(dirPath , pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

EDIT:
All work just fine! Create 2 console app as follow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This exe is runned from another exe.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pattern = "ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    string dirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if (files.Length > 0) Process.Start(files[0]);
    else Debug.WriteLine("File not found");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Place them in one folder, run App2. It WILL FIND App1 and run. Even if App1 will be in sub folder!

Comment: How to get the path as string? I assign var object to Directory.GetFiles(dirPath , pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories); . It does't work. object reference error occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of searching you could add the path as a configuration parameter in web.config.

Comment: This cannot be done, because I'm going to isolate this class library and then it is able to use any visual studio solution. If i add the path to web.config, then it has a dependency with MVC web project.